# Self-hosted CodeCov 401 unauthorised after redirect to self-hosted gitlab

Tags: gitlab, codecov

Self-hosted CodeCov 401 unauthorised after redirect to self-hosted gitlab.

Summary:
I added CodeCov as an application to my self-hosted gitlab.
When clicking login on CodeCov I am redirected to gitlab to authorise and once authorised bring me back to login screen.

Logs:

```
{"message": "Unauthorized: /internal/user", "asctime": "2024-01-30 10:42:05,194", "name": "django.request", "levelname": "WARNING", "lineno": 241, "pathname": "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", "funcName": "log_response", "threadName": "MainThread", "status_code": 401, "request": "<WSGIRequest: GET '/internal/user'>", "logger.name": "django.request", "logger.thread_name": "MainThread", "level": "WARNING"}
{"remote_address": "192.168.16.9", "request_time": "[30/Jan/2024:10:42:05 +0000]", "request": "GET /internal/user HTTP/1.1", "status_code": "401", "response_length": "58", "referer": "http://localhost:8080/gle", "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
```

I tried with different permissions on the gitlab side but no success. I also tried changing the redirect URI to localhost:8080/gle and that also didn't work.